# Redirect subdomains + http to https using mod_rewrite in Apache Virtual Host

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I have a virtual host with 1 name and 2 alias, `name.domain.com.br`, `alias1.domain.com.br` and `alias2.domain.com.br`. I need to redirect alias `1` and `2` to `name`, but it's not working completely, this is my current code:

```
ServerName name.domain.com.br
ServerAlias alias1.domain.com.br
ServerAlias alias2.domain.com.br
DocumentRoot ****************
ErrorLog ****************
CustomLog ****************
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =alias1.domain.com.br [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =alias2.domain.com.br [OR]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://name.domain.com.br [L,R=301]
```

However, this way the redirecting is only working when using `http://aliasX.domain.com.br` and for some reason it puts two slashes at the end of the link, getting `https://name.domain.com.br//`. It doesn't work when `https://` is used.

I want all variations with or without https to redirect to `https://name.domain.com.br`.

can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =alias1.domain.com.br [OR]
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =alias2.domain.com.br [OR]
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://name.domain.com.br [L,R=301]
> ```
>
> It doesn't work when "https://" is used.

HTTP and HTTPS require two separate virtual host containers.

No doubt you've put these rules in the virtual host for HTTP only, eg. `<VirtualHost *:80>`. You would need to repeat the redirect in the virtual host for HTTPS as well. eg. `<VirtualHost *:443>`. (Although the redirect in the HTTP vHost can be simplified, since you just need to redirect *everything* to HTTPS - see my solution below.)

HOWEVER, the rule you've posted is incorrect. Due to the erroneous `OR` flag on the last *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive), the redirect will *always* occur, effectively *unconditionally*.

You are also discarding the URL-path and redirecting to the homepage? (The browser corrects the missing slash.) I assume this is an error and you should be redirecting `alias1.domain.com.br/foo` to `name.domain.com.br/foo`, not `name.domain.com.br/`?

> for some reason it puts two slashes at the end of the link

That is not caused by this rule. Something else must be doing that.

So, the solution then becomes...

```
###
### HTTP (not secure)
###
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName name.domain.com.br
ServerAlias alias1.domain.com.br
ServerAlias alias2.domain.com.br
DocumentRoot ****************
ErrorLog ****************
CustomLog ****************

# Redirect everything to HTTPS and canonical domain
# No need for mod_rewrite, a simple mod_alias Redirect will suffice
Redirect 301 / https://name.domain.com.br/
</VirualHost>

###
### HTTPS (secure)
###
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName name.domain.com.br
ServerAlias alias1.domain.com.br
ServerAlias alias2.domain.com.br
DocumentRoot ****************
ErrorLog ****************
CustomLog ****************

# Other SSL directives here...

# Redirect to the canonical domain
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=name.domain.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://name.domain.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirualHost>
```

The redirect in the `HTTPS` vHost checks that the request is not already for the canonical hostname, rather than checking that it is one of the aliases.

NB: When checking the requested hostname, use `HTTP_HOST` instead of `SERVER_NAME`. By default they are the same, however, depending on the server config, `SERVER_NAME` might reference the value of the `ServerName` directive, not the hostname the client requested.

You will need to clear your browser cache is cleared before testing, since any erroneous 301 (permanent) redirects will have been cached. Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

And as mentioned above, if you are still seeing a double slash at the start of the URL-path then something else is doing that.